# How Would You Say: ${(x,y,z)|5x+2y+z=3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Currently studying systems of linear equations, and came across this statement:

$\{(x,y,z)\, |\, 5x+2y+z=3\}$

I know what what the statement means, I understand that it involves set notation, I just don't know how to 
articulate statements of set notation when it involves ordered-pairs/ordered-triples.

Can someone please help me articulate this statement. Thank you.

Comment: What statement do you mean? All you have written down so far is a set.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If by articulate you just mean "read out loud" then the notation means: This is the set of triples $(x,y,z)$ such that the equation $5x + 2y + z = 3$ holds. Can you elaborate what do you find confusing about "ordered triples"? The ordering here is important since obviously $x,y,z$ have different roles in the equation.

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Ok, I am new to online discussion boards, so please excuse me for not following/comprehending your posting structure. What I do understand, is that the notation I used is for making a statement/or indication of dependent equations. 5x

Comment: There aren't any dependent equations here. It just indicates the set of triples like $(0,0,3)$ or $(1,-1,0)$ (to name two) that satisfy the constraint on the right-hand side of the dividing line.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician The set notation was taken out of context. Consider the following system of linear equations: 3x+5y+3z=2, 6x+5y+z=0, 3x+10y-2z=6  The system is dependent, and to indicate that, you would use the notation {(x,y,z)|3x+5y+3z=2}  , "The set of all ordered triples (x,y,z), such that 3x+5y+3z=2 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the set of all ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $5x+2y+z=3$.

Comment: I like that, sounds pretty accurate. As I said, the notation {(x,y,z)|5x+2y+z=3 is(or can be) used to indicate that equations within a system are dependent, and thus equivalent and share the same set of points. If the system were to involve, for example, 5x+2y+z=3 & 7x+5x+3z=24, you would use 5x+2y+z=3 in the notation, because that equation has coefficients of a lesser value.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of that can be thought of every point in space, $(x,y,z)$, such that they should solve the equation $5x+2y+z=3$. So for example:
$$
A = \left(1,\frac{1}{2},-3\right)
$$
where
$$
x=1\text{ , }
y=\frac{1}{2}\text{ , }
z=-3
$$
and is an ordered-triple that solves your equation, so that point is a point in the "solution world", because:
$$
5(1) + 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (-3) = 3
$$
Another example is the origin $(0,0,0)$. It isn't in the "solution world". When I say "solution world", I mean the set of all ordered-triples that solves your equation.

I don't know if you know about planes, but $5x+2y+z = 3$ can be seen as a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because when you plot all the points in the canonical coordinate system, you'll actually get a plane and see that as a geometric interpretation of the "solution world".

[image]

It's important to say that what I've just said is a *geometric interpretation* of what you were asking. When you go above triples, you are "kinda" losing it but everything still holds.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes Thank you, I had already completely understood the notation, I just didn't know how to state it. The notation was taught to me as I studied systems of linear equations. You use such notation to indicate that a system is dependent, that each equation within the system will share the same set of ordered pairs/triples...

Comment: Yes, that's right @IamPyre. Good luck with your studies! Cya